# C#: Getting a button to display a preset form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I (currently) have two forms, one that needs to call the other. In other words, by clicking a certain button in `Form1`, `Form2` needs to "pop up", like a dialog box. I know I have to get a reference in both forms, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this. What is a decent tutorial/beginner site to learn about GUIs in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 myForm = new Form2();
    myForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

`ShowDialog` forces the user to close that window before s/he can access the rest of the application.